# What's the easiest way of adding more options in the Theme Options of the twenty eleven theme?

Tags: themes, options

[Wordpress 3.2 beta](http://wordpress.org/wordpress-3.2-beta2.zip) comes with twenty eleven.
It has a Theme Option panel in the Appearance section:

[image]

I would like to know what's the easiest (and extendible) way of adding more options to that panel. For instance, changing the color of other elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in [source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/inc/theme-options.php) theme makes some use of [Settings API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API), but doesn't include calls like `do_settings_fileds()` that would allow you to use add settings.

I would probably try to unhook `twentyeleven_theme_options_add_page()` call and fork that and `theme_options_render_page()` to extend it with additional options.

Also I think that unlike core Twenty Eleven wasn't declared to be ready yet. Things might change.